# numpy array type hint multiple fields

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

How do you type hint for numpy arrays with fields like `[('reference', 'O'), ('check', '?')]` (referenece is to a python object and check is a boolean)

currently my type hint

```py
np.ndarray[typing.Any, np.dtype[[('reference', 'O'), ('check', '?')]]]
```

doesn't work as there is a list inside, giving the error `List expression not allowed for this type argument(Pylance)`

The last I found on this issue is this comment [type hint for structured array discussion](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/7370#issuecomment-908308757)

Comment: Did you try the vice-versa version of your type hint like this: `np.ndarray[np.dtype([('reference', 'O'), ('check', '?')]), typing.Any]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Unfortunately we couldn't expect that structured arrays are supported by a mypy-friendly manner in the near future

This was said by the user `odashi` in the [issue](https://github.com/neulab/ExplainaBoard/issues/385) (16 Aug 2022)

The challenges faced by the developers are listed here in this comment of the [main numpy
typing issue/discussion](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/7370#issuecomment-908308757)